# dmarc getting fail in Authentication result

Tags: postfix-mta, dkim

I am having Postfix server configured for domain. From last few days my mails are marking as spam in gmail. I have already configured DKIM,SPF and DMARC for this domain. I have checked mail source and getting

"Authentication-Results: mydomain; dmarc=fail header.from=mydomain"

I have checked all the support docs but didn`t find anything.

Comment: DMARC failure should not affect your spam score. The mail might be classified as SPAM due to other reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide full sample headers or run a classification test with [a third party](https://www.mail-tester.com/)?

Often, the TXT records aren't correctly created with the proper name style or have a syntax error causing the mail server parser to fail. Since DMARC fails the issue can be in either SPF or DKIM. In relaxed mode, the [SPF]-authenticated domain and RFC5322.From domain must have the same Organizational Domain. In strict mode, only an exact DNS domain match is considered to produce [Identifier Alignment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489#section-3.1).

Generally speaking, its really hard to help without proper details. Kindly always provide DNS and configuration samples.